# TRIGGER MYSQL QUE ANEXE Y ELIMINE

Tags: sql, trigger

Necesito hacer un **trigge**r por el cual, al cambiar un dato de una tabla (SUSPENDIDO DE "NO" a "SI"), automáticamente ese registro pase a una tabla con el nombre PRODUCTOS SUSPENDIDOS y se borre de la tabla original (PRODUCTOS NEPTUNO).

He escrito el siguiente trigger pero me tira error cuando modifico un valor de la tabla:

```
USE PRUEBA;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER MOVER_PRODUCTOS BEFORE UPDATE ON PRODUCTOS_NEPTUNO 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS_SUSPENDIDOS(IDPRODUCTO,
NOMBREPRODUCTO,NOMBRECONTACTO,NOMBRECATEGORIA,PRECIOUNIDAD,SUSPENDIDO,IDPROVEEDOR,PRECIO_FINAL,
PAIS_ORIGEN)
    VALUES(OLD.IDPRODUCTO,OLD.NOMBREPRODUCTO,
OLD.NOMBRECONTACTO,OLD.NOMBRECATEGORIA,
OLD.PRECIOUNIDAD,NEW.SUSPENDIDO,OLD.IDPROVEEDOR,
OLD.PRECIO_FINAL,OLD.PAIS_ORIGEN);
DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS_NEPTUNO WHERE SUSPENDIDO='SI';
END;$$
UNLOCK(PRODUCTOS_NEPTUNO);
DELIMITER ;
```

> ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'productos_neptuno' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger. SQL Statement: UPDATE
>   `prueba`.`productos_neptuno` SET `SUSPENDIDO`='si' WHERE
>   `IdProducto`='14'

Alguien me podría decir si tiene solución?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Necesitas hacer esto en un Store Procedure. Un trigger no puede actualizar la tabla donde esta, porque eso provocaria una recursion infinita (se actualiza la tabla -> llama al trigger -> se actualiza la tabla -> llama al trigger.. etc)...

Comment: Una duda, es inviable hacer la eliminación directa del registro en ves de marcarlo como SI?, ya que podrías hacer que el trigger se dispare cuando se haga ese delete.

Comment: En realidad, lo que yo necesito, es que al cambiar el dato SUSPENDIDO por SI en la tabla A, ese registro pase a la tabla B y se borre de la tabla A, todo de manera automática a través de un trigger.

Comment: ¿Y por que no implementas una baja lógica en vez de una física, con un simple `update`? Por otro lado, (no recuerdo) con un trigger `AFTER UPDATE`, no podrías?

Comment: No, no se puede con el `AFTER UPDATE`.

Comment: Una cosa que puedes hacer es un cambio en la lógica del programa. Me explico: en vez de lanzar un `UPDATE` para hacer el cambio de `SUSPENDIDO` a `SI`, lanzas un `DELETE` de ese registro teniendo al mismo tiempo un `TRIGGER BEFORE DELETE` que te inserte el registro en la `tablaB` antes de ser borrado. Así te ahorras un `UPDATE` que si lo miras bien no tiene sentido porque la fila en ese caso debería ser borrada de la tabla según lo que dices. Y el `TRIGGER` funcionará, porque actuará sobre una `tablaB` que no está implicada en la acción que lo lanzó.

Comment: Excelente respuesta!