# Eliminando un registro recien insertado con un trigger en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo la necesidad de evaluar un registro que esta siendo insertado en una tabla de MySQL, la idea es que si la sentencia se cumple, el registro que se acaba de insertar sea eliminado.

Este es el código de mi trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ValidaMant AFTER INSERT ON MANTENIMIENTOS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.NUM_MANT_MES>NEW.MANT_X_MES THEN
    DELETE FROM mantenimientos WHERE id_mantenimiento = NEW.id_mantenimiento;
END IF;
END;$$
```

Se guarda bien el trigger en la tabla, si agrego un registro y no cumple con la sentencia `IF` sin problema me lo guarda, pero si la sentencia `IF` se cumple, me manda el siguiente error:

> #1442 - Can't update table 'mantenimientos' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

No encuentro el error, alguna sugerencia?

Saludos

Comment: el error es que no puede invocar un trigger en un procedure store que esta en el mismo lugar... eso provoca recurcion. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237032/trigger-mysql-que-anexe-y-elimine

Comment: Como Bienvenidx a SOes. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Procura siempre indicar en tus preguntas, la versión de las cosas que usas. En este caso, la versión de MySQL, porque la respuesta cambia de acuerdo a la versión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dos cosas:

1. efectivamente, no puedes correr un DML (select, insert, update, delete) sobre la tabla en la que está operando el trigger. Nunca.
2. Es mejor usar en tu aproximación un `before insert` (o `before insert or update`), cuando la fila técnicamente *no se ha insertado aún*. No estás afectando una función de agregación (un SUM o un COUNT) sobre la tabla; sólo estás mirando a ver si en la nueva fila el valor de una columna es mayor al de otra columna. No necesitas dejar que se inserte para hacer eso.

Para versiones recientes de MySQL, es posible usar un signal state para decirle a MySQL que la inserción ya no va. Ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ValidaMant BEFORE INSERT ON MANTENIMIENTOS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.NUM_MANT_MES > NEW.MANT_X_MES THEN
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

Así, cuando hagas el insert, el trigger lanzará la excepción que definiste.

```
mysql> insert into MANTENIMIENTOS values(1, 2, 3,...);
ERROR 1644 (45000): Unhandled user-defined exception condition
```

Como no indicas qué versión de MySQL estás usando, es necesario aclarar que para versiones anteriores (no recuerdo si es en 5.x o antes), esto no funciona y es necesario, esencialmente, hacer que la fila que se va a insertar incumpla algún constraint obvio.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ValidaMant BEFORE INSERT ON MANTENIMIENTOS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.NUM_MANT_MES > NEW.MANT_X_MES THEN
        set NEW.FILA_QUE_NO_PUEDE_SER_NULA = NULL
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

Con esto, logras que la fila no se inserte y devolverá error 1048 porque violó el constraint.

Comment: Gracias mi estimado!!!...efectivamente eso andaba buscando "ver la manera" de evitar que NO SE guardara...recibe un fuerte abrazo virtual.  Saludos.

Comment: @aahp me alegra poder ayudar. Buena suerte!